# jQuery Ajax two identical functions working for one and not the other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a comment system where a user can comment something to a post and then other users can reply to that comment. I have made a function to comment which works perfectly. I also wanted a similar function to work for that reply to comment part so I copied the same function and made some changes to the code like variable names etc. But its not working. When I write a reply and press enter it takes me to a new line rather than submitting. Please help me.

```
// COMMENT UPDATE (WORKING)

$(document).on('keydown', '.commentarea', function(event) {
    var comtt = $(".commentarea").val();
    if(comtt!=''){
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var status_id = id.replace("postcomment_", "");
            createComment(status_id);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function createComment(status_id){
  var comment = $('#postcomment_'+status_id).val();
  $.ajax({
      url: "post-comment.php",type: "POST",
      data: {comment : comment, statsid : status_id},
      success: function (data) {
        $("#showbox_"+status_id).append(data);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Ooops!! Problem Ocurred. Please try again later. If problem persists, please contact support!");
      },
      complete: function(xhr) {
        $('#postcomment_'+status_id).val('');
      }
  })
}

// REPLY TO COMMENT (SAME FUNCTION BUT NOT WORKING)

$(document).on('keydown', '.replyarea', function(event) {
    var comtr = $(".replyarea").val();
    if(comtr!=''){
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
            var rid = $(this).attr('id');
            var commentId = rid.replace("replycomment_", "");
            createReply(commentId);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function createReply(commentId){
  var creply = $('#replycomment_'+status_id).val();
  $.ajax({
      url: "post-replies.php",type: "POST",
      data: {creply : creply, cmtid : commentId},
      success: function (data) {
        $("#showreply_"+commentId).append(data);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Ooops!! Problem Ocurred. Please try again later. If problem persists, please contact support!");
      },
      complete: function(xhr) {
        $('#replycomment_'+commentId).val('');
      }
  })
}
```

PHP Part:

```
<?php while($get_stf = $get_stq->fetch()){ extract($get_stf); // fetch posts ?>

<?php while($fetch_cmts = $get_cmtq->fetch()){ extract($fetch_cmts); // fetch comments?>

 <!-- Reply to comments form -->

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="full-width" id="cmt_form_id_<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>" id="cmtsid_<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>" />

<textarea name="reply" placeholder="Give a reply..." class="reply-comment-field replyarea" id="replycomment_<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>"></textarea>

</form>
<!-- End Reply to comments form -->

<?php } ?>

<!-- Comment form -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="full-width" id="cmt_form_id_<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>" id="cmtsid_<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>" />

<textarea name="reply" placeholder="Give a reply..." class="reply-comment-field replyarea" id="replycomment_<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>"></textarea>

</form>
<!-- End Comment form -->

<?php } ?>
```

Both functions are same. But one being used for COMMENTS is working perfectly whereas the one used for REPLY TO COMMENTS is not working. It should submit the form and insert the data when I press enter in REPLY TO COMMENTS form after writing some text just like FACEBOOK. Please help.

Comment: you can separate what the script works and what is not working ??

Comment: see the code.. updated the comment stating which one is working and which one is not.. also please look at the forms respectively for diagnosing the error.. thanks in advance buddy :)

Comment: have you copied the wrong comment html? as its identical the the reply form.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not error detectors (Debuger); if you can tell that section of code occurs error and resolve not know: we can work together to fix it. you better present your question.

Comment: @BenG yes I copied the form too.. but I have changed the attribute values used in it

Comment: @WalterNuñez with diagnose I meant to help me fix the problem....

Comment: @WalterNuñez I already stated which code is working and which is not working..

Comment: before ajax function put this: console.log(creply + ' -> ' + cmtid); view and paste your result on update.

Comment: Hey.. solved 50%.. code is working now.. its inserting data.. but its working for the 1st result in while loop only.. means i can reply with only the 1st reply button.. but with others it not working..

Answer (score 0):

your comment is broken the code:

Change this:

```
<!-- Reply to comments form -- >
```

for this:

```
 <!-- Reply to comments form -->
```

and update.

Comment: you should have used comments section for saying so.. this is not an answer buddy...